# Convert/Adjust Number in a specific counting with PHP

Tags: php, count, numbers

I have the number 1543, I want to make sure that I find the number closest to 1543 which is counted every 100. For eg:

> 1527 = 1500
>
> 1563 = 1600
>
> 12034 = 12000
>
> 12081 = 12100

I hope that you understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function with a precision value of `-2`,

```
round( $number, -2);
```

[Codepad Viper Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LPm36H)

Comment: Perfect, last question: how can I do it the same by counting every 50? But up to 1000 eg. 232=250, 264=300, 783=800, 721=750... If the number is greater "1000" it use the first method.

Comment: In that case I think you need to use ghost suggested method like `echo round(235 / 50) * 50;`

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by dividing the number by 100 and using the [round](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    function foo($number, $d)
    {
        return round($number / $d) * $d;
    }

    echo foo(1527, 100) . "\n";
    echo foo(12081, 100) . "\n";

?>
```