# PHP - get closest number given a certain number?

Tags: php, numbers, closest

I'm modifying one of OpenCart's product filters to filter products in/out by price. What I do is get all products belonging to a certain category and extract their prices to put them in a slider, but this is not elegant or 'professional' at all, and I would like to code a proper solution.

Let's say I have the following prices: 125, 270, 517, 1680 and 14790. What I would like to do (ideally) is get the highest number (14790 in this short example) and, from it, get something like '15000', so I can divide that between a given factor (like 100) and put that into a slider.

Is there a PHP function to do this kind of calculation?

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935390/convert-adjust-number-in-a-specific-counting-with-php/14935471#14935471

Comment: Good approach, it's not exactly what I was looking for but I have an idea about where to use that one. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the max number, then round it up to the nearest thousand?

```
<?php

$largest = max(125, 270, 517, 1680, 14790);

$nearest = ceil($largest / 1000) * 1000;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, and you're asking to round to essentially the nearest 100, there isn't a specific function, but with a bit of maths you can round to the nearest hundred like so:

```
$price = ceil($price / 100) * 100;
```

Using:

```
$price = ceil($price / 1000) * 1000;
```

Would round to the nearest 1000.

Comment: Good thought. The answer was quite close to it, the ceil function was key to determine the closest number. I followed @sjdaws answer and I got what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop through the numbers, remembering the highest value as you go. It's common coding practice. (Ok there really is a max() function as well, *echo max(1, 3, 5, 6, 7);  // 7*)

Then you could divide the highest number by your factor, take the integer you get and add one to it, then multiply by the factor again and there you go.

Answer (score 1):

just do : x=floor(14790/100) ; the floor function returns the next lowest integer value

Comment: Hmmm not exactly what I was looking for, but thanks for the answer :)